# XML item is the same as php key word

Tags: php

I have xml item

```
<parent>0</parent>
```

in my xml file. I need to add it to the variable in PHP such as

```
$parent = htmlspecialchars($fce_pridej_polozka_kategorie_xml->parent);
```

But parent is the keyword of PHP so the command is not functional.

What to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this within a parent class?  If so:

```
//The 'this' keyword references the current object
$this->parent = htmlspecialchars($fce_pridej_polozka_kategorie_xml->parent);
```

Comment: My problem is the word parent inside the bracket. Not the name of the variable. Or did I understand your suggestion wrong?

Comment: Just tested your code directly and I don't have any issues.  It works as expected.  What version are you running?  I'm on 5.5.1.

Comment: How to do a if with this variable? Because this helped me not.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->parent = htmlspecialchars($fce_pridej_polozka_kategorie_xml->parent);
   if($parent == 0){
      $name = substr_replace(htmlspecialchars($fce_pridej_polozka_kategorie_xml -> fieldname), '', 0, 2);
   }
   else{
      $name = htmlspecialchars($fce_pridej_polozka_kategorie_xml -> fieldname);
   }
```

Comment: This part is not functional.